# Java - Not the expected format from Locale

Tags: java, kotlin, locale, simpledateformat, datetimeformatter

I'm having some issues in some countries, on this case is with the `Locale("cs", "CZ")` the format of the date I'm looking for is `dd. MM.` but is returning `dd.MM.`, how can I solve this?

I'm trying to get the pattern doing this :

```
val pattern = DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(locale, "ddMM")
val dateFormatted = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern,locale).withLocale(locale).format(date)
```

But the problem is since I'm using this Locale it's somehow assigned with an unexpected date formatter.

How can I get this `dd. MM.` pattern?

The code is in *kotlin* but i tag *java* so if you put a Java answer and it works I'll mark it as a correct one.

Comment: It seems to me that with `withLocale(locale)` you are basically overriding whatever pattern you have configured.

Comment: So, how do I change the pattern then? @JoãoDias I'm creating the Locale as I put Locale("cs", "CZ") and then I want to override the date format

Comment: @user16320675 because I need it to be formatted with the correct way, for instance in CZ it's DD. MM. and locale does it automatically for you but in this case is wrong and I just want to override the format date only for this Locale.

Comment: @user16320675 what is being displayed is "dd.MM." and I want "dd. MM."

Comment: Which `DateFormat` class is that? Mine hasn’t got a `getBestDateTimePattern` method (I have got `java.text.DateFormat`, a class that I don’t recommend using).

Answer (score 2):

If you need a pattern for the complete date, [`DateTimeFormatter#ofLocalizedDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) meets your requirement precisely. However, if you need to restrict it to just days and months, the options are limited. I have shown a couple of the options below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("cs", "CZ");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).localizedBy(locale);
        // Test
        String formatted = dtf1.format(LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println(formatted);
        // If you are required to remove year, do it explicitly
        formatted = formatted.replaceAll("\\s+\\d{4}", "");
        System.out.println(formatted);

        // Or use a fixed format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MM.", locale);
        // Test
        System.out.println(dtf2.format(LocalDate.now()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
7. 10. 2021
7. 10.
07. 10.
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/G9OevW)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Comment: But I'm doing this : ddMM where the locale format this ddMM as it's defined by ISO. But I don't get why there's no space in cs_CZ other countries works good

Comment: Just curious, what did you mean that ddMM is defined by ISO? (I thought it was a Unicode thing, I may be mistaken.)